# ORA-00917: missing comma error, when column desc is having spanish words

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

```
insert into tab (ID, DESCRIPRION) values (1,'FARMACIAS PHARMACY´S');
```

getting following error.

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00917: missing comma

my description is in spanish language.

Please let me know, how to fix above error.

Comment: Also you've shown the penultimate character in your string as an angled quote mark `´`; is it really that, or a curly quote, or a normal straight quote (which would give this error, and would need to be escaped as Marius showed)?

Comment: Or really it looks like an acute accent `´` (U+0084 I think?). it's really much more helpful to show us the actual statement that generates the error, copied and pasted from the session that generated it.Otherwise we're distracted by side issues like invalid column names and possibly incorrectly retyped values...

Comment: If those values are coming from application code like php, .net, coldfusion, etc, use query paramters.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the q-quote syntax for quoting a string...

```
insert into junk values ( 1, q'[FARMACIAS PHARMACY´S]' );
```

Comment: Does that make any difference when the string contains an acute accent rather than a single straight quote character?

Comment: @AlexPoole. Not from my testing. It's convenient way to quote any string without having to try and figure out how to escape quotes etc .  Try it out...

Comment: Yeah, but there isn't a quote to escape *8-) Well, I'm almost certain there is really and the value is mangled in the question, but still...

Comment: ... which doesn't need to be escaped. I'm not sure it is a backquote, but it isn't a simple straight quote.

Answer (score -1):

DESC is a keyword. Wrap it in double quotes

```
insert into tab (ID, "DESC") values (1,'ABC FRMACY´S');
```